# Double equal to signs in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, variable-assignment

So if I say something like n = 5, that obviously means I'm assigning the integer 5 to the variable n. But what does it mean when the syntax is:

a = b = 0

Is it assigning 0 to a and b? Or is assigning b = 0 to a? Or something else?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: _Is it assigning 0 to a and b?_ yes.